# Update the render every time the props object is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I am making an expense tracker. I am receiving an object of data in the income component as props. I want to render it only when the object is updated / new data is passed to the object, I want the new data is rendered along with the previous data. But every time I pass the first data, the component returns 2 empty div. How can I stop getting 2 empty div's at first render.

```
const Income = ({incomeData}) => {
  const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(0)
  const [displayData, setDisplayData] = useState([])

  

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(incomeData.amount) setTotalAmount(totalAmount + incomeData.amount)
    setDisplayData((prevData)=> [...prevData, incomeData])
  }, [incomeData])


  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
       <div className={totalAmount > 0 ? style.main : style.mainBlock}>
       <h1>Total Income: {totalAmount}</h1>
        {displayData.map((data, idx)=>{
            const {total, type, date, amount, income, id} = data
          return (
            <div key={id} className={style.incomeBox}>
            <div className={style.incomeDetail}>
               <p>{income}</p>
               <div>
                 <span>{amount}</span>
                 <span>{date}</span>
               </div>
            </div>
                  <button id={id}>
                    <AiFillDelete />
                  </button>
            </div>
          )
        })}
       </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Income
```

I am expecting the 2 empty data not to be displayed in the income list.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you’re passing in empty objects for `previousData` and `incomeData`. If that’s the case then what’s rendered initially will be empty values b/c there’s no initial data.

Your options are to either pass in data on the initial render, or hide elements if data is empty. As you have a number of divs, this is just a guess at what you want to hide.

```
   return (
    <div className={style.container}>
       <div className={totalAmount > 0 ? style.main : style.mainBlock}>
       <h1>Total Income: {totalAmount}</h1>
        {displayData[0].amount && displayData[1].amount && displayData.map((data, idx)=>{
            const {total, type, date, amount, income, id} = data
          return (
            <div key={id} className={style.incomeBox}>
            <div className={style.incomeDetail}>
               <p>{income}</p>
               <div>
                 <span>{amount}</span>
                 <span>{date}</span>
               </div>
            </div>
                  <button id={id}>
                    <AiFillDelete />
                  </button>
            </div>
          )
        })}
       </div>
    </div>
  )
```

The idea being that with a conditional check before the mapping of data you can either hide or display based on whether data is initially provided.